# Sharepoint Client Object Model locale

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, localization

Is there a way to get the Sharepoint locale (not the language) from the Client Object Model?
With the Server Object Model we have `SPWeb.Locale` but Client.Web.Locale does not exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint CSOM is not offering the Locale property. I think the easiest way to retrieve the Locale Propertyvalue is to use SharePoint WCF hosting capabilities and host a custom WCFservice which itself is able to connect directly to the serverside SPWeb instances and retrieve the PropertyValue

Thorsten